# How to run vbs from Python?

Tags: python, vbscript

I'm working on a GitHub project. It's a text editor built in Python. I need to be able to run `error.vbs` from `test.py`.

How or **is** this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Nevermind.

I just found it out:

```
import os
os.system("filename.vbs 1")
```

Comment: just opens the file in texteditor